# This one time/ This one time when--- Are both the sentences used in the post grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

This one time, I was walking down the street and I bumped into X. He proceeded to initiate a conversation, and in 20 minutes, we had had a good conversation.

This one time **when** I was walking down the street, I bumped into X. He proceeded to initiate a conversation.....

Is **this one time** usually followed by when? Or is there nothing wrong with the first sentence?
Do both the sentences mean the same?

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about **this one time when** though the usual collocation is **this one time** without **when** because what usually follows after it is an independent clause.  *This one time, we were all together at our favorite restaurant and....*

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions

> this one time
>   this one time *when*

have the same meaning. The first is an abbreviated version of the second, which is usually used when spoken.

Usually "when" is used

> There was a time *when*
>   This one time *when*
>   It was during the holiday season *when*